# Countries with hi-tech toilets

Tags: factoids, hygiene, countries

While in Japan I was amazed by the hi-tech toilets I saw everywhere (even in rural areas) and I even felt a bit inferior because Italians' toilet don't offer anywhere near such a range of personal experiences.

What are other countries where these kinds of toilets are common?

[image: hi-tech toilet]

Comment: I can't even recall ever seeing one in Korea.

Comment: There are plenty of these in upscale hotels in the US. Not to mention people putting them up in their homes

Comment: @Geeo I have to be honest, that is bizarre !

Comment: What do all those buttons *do*?

Comment: One warm up the toilet, another spray water, another one play some sound in order to conceal your inner sounds etc. But the creepiest one is labeled "massage". I didnt dare to press it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I saw several in the bigger cities in China when we were there this month - e.g. Shanghai and Beijing. That said, from what I've heard about Japan I don't think they are as prevalent in China.

I didn't see even one 'fancy' toilet in any other country we visited in Asia: Vietnam, Indonesia, Thailand, Cambodia, Burma, Sri Lanka, India, Nepal, Malaysia. We spent about a month in each and intermittently visited more expensive establishments so I guess we got a reasonable idea of what's around...

This general observation is also supported by [the Wikipedia article I just checked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilets_in_Japan):

> The largest producer is Toto, with 65% of the market share, while the second largest is Inax at 25%.[6][20] The main market for washlets is still in Japan, and TOTO reports that overseas sales account for just 5% of its revenue.[6] The primary foreign market is China, where Toto sells over one million washlets each year.

Comment: In Vietnam I only saw those toilets in some Japanese companies